# Saving a variable after closing browser

Tags: javascript, html

Ok so I got a simple script, that increase a number when a button is pressed:

```
<script>
var count = 0;
    var button = document.getElementById("countButton");
    var display = document.getElementById("displayCount");

    button.onclick = function(){
        count++;
        display.innerHTML = count;
        } </script>
```

This is the button: `<input type="button" value="Count" id="countButton" />`

And this is the number: `<span id="displayCount">0</span>`

My problem is, that the number is starting again from 0 when I refresh the page. What I want, for example, if I press the button twice and then restart the browser, the page will display number "2", not 0.

Some help?

Comment: look at the `localStorage`: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

Comment: If you want to avoid localStorage, there is also just using cookies: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document/cookie

Comment: 1st thought try window.onunload

Comment: Your best bet if you want the data to be saved is to use a db or xml file on the server. You would need to use the onunload or I remember reading about a U.S. Event that was something like before unload. Make an Ajax request and save it. This means even if the user clears the cookies/local storage your data will still be accessible. I'm on the phone right now but I'll post an answer later

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Local storage seems to be the thing you want.

```
var count = 0;
if(localStorage.btncount){count=localStorage.btncount;} //check if you have already stored it; set count to it if yes
    var button = document.getElementById("countButton");
    var display = document.getElementById("displayCount");
    display.innerHTML = count;
    button.onclick = function(){
        count++;
        localStorage.btncount=count; // store the count
        display.innerHTML = count;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use localStorage API.

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

Not tested.

```
<script>
    var count = localStorage.getItem("count") || 0;
    var button = document.getElementById("countButton");
    var display = document.getElementById("displayCount");

    button.onclick = function() {
        count++;
        display.innerHTML = count;

        localStorage.setItem("count", count);
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because the script is reloaded every time you refresh the page.

The most modern/simple solution to solve this is using webstorage (local/session storage in the browser) which was introduced with HTML5.

With this you could do:

```
localStorage.setItem('count', '0');
var incrementedCount = localStorage.getItem('count') + 1;
localStorage.setItem('count', incrementedCount);
```

`localStorage` (and `sessionStorage`) is a property on the window object and can be used to save data inbetween browser sessions, `sessionStorage` will only keep the data in one session and is less useful for your use case.

It's a very simple API to use and at the moment it can only store strings, so to store objects you need to use `JSON.stringify` and `JSON.parse`

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to local storage is using cookies.  Save the value in a cookie before the browser closes using window.onbeforeunload then access it when the page loads.  http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

Comment: It's a possibility, but this approach would not work if the user sets its browser not to keep cookies.